# ViewPager widget not taking assigned weight

Tags: android, android-layout, viewpagerindicator

I tried to change my frame layout to viewpager layout. However, I can't make my viewpager layout to take the same space as frame layout. This frame layout is taking 4 weight place of its parent. How can I organize my viewpager to take the same space?

frame layout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4">
```

viewpager layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is because you have applied weight for `LinearLayout` not for `ViewPager`. And you have set 0 dp height for ViewPager so you can't get properly.

Comment: First Linear Layout takes 4 weight through all layout. I set 1 weightsum to first layout. ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator share this weight. I added linear layout to both viewpager and indicator.   Which layout are you talking about? First Layout or linearlayout of viewpager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewpager will take entire screen width by default. You can change it by [**overriding  float getPageWidth method**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth%28int%29)

It accepts value from 0-1. **in your case you return 0.8**

```
public float getPageWidth (int position)
{
return 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I am using ViewPagerIndicator library and it's giving me classcastexception when I tried to add a CustomViewPager that extends ViewPager and then change the ViewPager with CustomViewPager.

Comment: Okey, solved. In the layout, I gave the custom widget name and it worked. Thanks.